# C Two structs cause segmentation fault 11

Tags: c, struct

I'm trying to run this code. If it is ran like this it works, but as soon as the second struct is uncommented it fails with a "Segmentation fault: 11". What am I doing wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func();

typedef struct foo
{
    double one;
    double two;
} foo;


int main() {

    func();
    printf("ret");

    foo *f;
    f->one = 10;
    f->two = 10;

//    foo *g;
//    g->one = 10;
//    g->two = 10;


return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're dereferencing an uninitialized pointer. There's also an undefined function `func` so you should get a link error.

Comment: `f` is never allocated

Comment: With `foo *f;` you define a pointer variable `f`. But *where does it point*? Remember that local variables in C are not initialized when defined, their values are *indeterminate* (and seemingly random).

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with structures.

Comment: @Ôrel Technically the variable `f` itself is allocated. However, there's no allocated memory for it to point to.

Comment: Not looking at the compiler warnings. That's what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Compile with -Wall -Wextra. This is undefined behavior which means ANYTHING may happen, including the program working as it is supposed to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably intended to do this:

```
foo f;
f.one = 10;
f.two = 10;
```

Here `f` is not a *pointer* to a `foo` but it *is* a `foo`.

When you write `foo *f;`, then `f` is a *pointer*, and you need to assign a valid memory address to it before you can dereference it, for example as in Marievi's answer.

You should probably read the chapter dealing with pointers in your C text book.

Comment: wow I did not realise that this was the mistake. I have had a rather brief introduction to C, I'll take another look at the chapter about pointers.

Answer (score 2):

You declare pointer `foo` but you also need to allocate memory for it :

```
foo *f = malloc(sizeof(struct foo));
if (f == NULL)
    return;
```

because right now, you have it uninitialized but try to de-reference it.

Answer (score 0):

UB warning!!!

Here - `foo *g;` you only declare a pointer. It points to memory you don't yet own (haven't `malloc()` it). Trying to de-reference such a pointer is UB and can cause (in your case **does** cause, a segfault).

Note that the same goes for your `foo *f;`. `malloc()` both and them.

Oh, and **READ COMPILER WARNINGS!!** (`warning: 'g' is used uninitialized in this function`)

Two ways to fix this:

1. don't use pointers... change `foo *g;` into `foo g` and `g->one = 10` into `g.one = 10`. *in this case, the memory is allocated to you on declaration*
2. allocate memory... add this line `g = malloc(sizeof(*g));` after `foo *g;` (and also after foo *f). _here, the memory is allocated by you and would have to be released afterwards by you!! (using `free(g);` )